# Laravel: Add a join to self referencing Many-to-Many relationship?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, many-to-many, self-join, self-reference

We have a self referencing product-to-product relationship, and I am struggling to return data based on another FK in the pivot table.

I'm playing with a sample pivot table that looks like this:
**tmp_prod2prod:**

- id
- prod_id_to
- prod_id_from
- affiliation_type_id

And that `affiliation_type_id` FK refers to this table:
**affiliation_types:**

- id
- type
- description

(BTW, if you want to see a full schema, [find it here on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/TLvVNJcf))

**GOAL:**
My goal is to show `affiliation_types.type`.

My model looks like:

```
class TmpProd extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'tmp_prods';
    public $timestamps = false;


    public function affiliatedToProducts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('TmpProd', 'tmp_prod2prod', 'p_id_to', 'p_id_from')
            ->withPivot('affiliation_type_id')
            ->join('affiliation_types', 'tmp_prod2prod.affiliation_type_id', '=', 'affiliation_types.id');
    }

    public function affiliatedFromProducts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('TmpProd', 'tmp_prod2prod', 'p_id_from', 'p_id_to');
    }

}
```

and my controller I'm running:

```
    $model = TmpProd::find(1);
    foreach ($model->affiliatedToProducts as $cross) {
        echo"<pre>",var_dump($cross->pivot),"</pre>\n";
    }
```

I've tried enough variations that I feel like my head is spinning :)
How do I reconcile the `affiliation_types.type` based on the `affiliation_type_id` FK in the pivot table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going round and round with custom pivot models, all sorts of convoluted relations, etc., I believe I've found a simple solution—just add a `select` statement to your relation, targeting the `affiliation_types` table, so that you have access to the `types` column:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('TmpProd', 'tmp_prod2prod', 'p_id_to', 'p_id_from')
    ->withPivot('affiliation_type_id')
    ->join('affiliation_types', 'tmp_prod2prod.affiliation_type_id', '=', 'affiliation_types.id')
    ->addSelect('affiliation_types.type as affiliation_type');
```

(The `as affiliation_type` part is optional, but will make your query clearer semantically.)

Then, in your `foreach` loop, you can call:

```
var_dump($cross->affiliation_type);
```

It would also be a good idea to eager-load your `affiliatedToProducts` relations, to reduce the number of queries from N+1 down to 2. So, to find a particular product by ID:

```
$model = TmpProd::with('affiliatedToProducts')->find(1);
```

Or, if you need to retrieve all products:

```
$model = TmpProd::with('affiliatedToProducts')->get();
```

...then loop over the results with `foreach ($model as $m)`.

---

**Update:** This worked for Laraval v4.2.8, but as of v4.2.11, it seems (counterintuitively) that `->addSelect` *replaces*, rather than *adds*, the query's original `select` statement, and is functionally identical to just using `->select`. So for versions newer than 4.2.8, it is necessary to add the original table back into the query, so the `belongsToMany` relation should end with:

```
->select('affiliation_types.type', 'tmp_prods.*');
```

Comment: Adding `addSelect` used to (as of 4.2.8), well, **add** a select statement. Now, in 4.2.11, it **replaces** the original select statement, at least in the case of `belongsToMany` relations, and is functionally identical to just using `select`. I'm trying to figure out why this changed, but for now, the only solution would be to specify `tmp_prods.*`, so `->select('affiliation_types.type', 'tmp_prods.*');`. Or downgrade to v4.2.8. :)